# Why does my armature rig deform badly in edit mode?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, import

Im fairly new to blender and am at the stage where i'm trying to figure everything out. Everytime I import a motion capture file the animations work and looks good. But when i go into edit mode to scale and put it in place with my mesh the armature rig is flat on the ground. Then i try to put all the bones in their respective locations but then the mesh is heavily deformed in pose and object mode again.And the animation is also really screwed up as a result. Why is this happening and how do i fix it?[image: Armature Fine After Import][image: Armature Deformed Edit Mode]

Comment: In edit mode you define the rest position (T-Pose) and in pose mode you deform the mesh when its rigged to the armature.

Comment: Hi Denis, so do i click on the rest position button and then just create the t-pose?

Comment: You need to position the armature to T-Pose in edit mode.